Override image.html.twig
How to override image.html.twig? I'm trying this:
    /**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter().
 */
function MYTHEME_theme_suggestions_image_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  $entity = $variables['item']->getEntity();
  $field_name = $variables['item']->getParent()->getName();
  $suggestions[] = 'image__' . $entity->getEntityTypeId() . '__' . $entity->bundle() . '__' . $field_name;
}

But it don't work. Maybe because my image output as responsive image.

How is it not working?

The image theme doesn't have an item variable, so this is never going to work. It would be a good idea to edit the question and provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish, and in what context
